# Auto layout doesn't work on iPhone 6 device but works on emulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have an app which uses auto layout constraints added in Xcode designer , mostly using "add missing constraints" option from Editor menu , problem is screens looks good on iPhone 6 iOS 8.3 emulator but doesn't work on actual iPhone 6 device iOS 8 as well. I m not adding anything from code 
Below are the examples

[image: Screen shot from iPhone 6 device]

[image: Screen shot from iPhone 6 emulator]

What am i missing with auto layout ?

**** additional details ***
[image: additional details]

[image: constraints]

[image: constraints1]

Comment: Is the phone running iOS 8.3 or earlier?

Comment: its at testers end but yes most likely

Comment: please post your constraints? or check this similar layout problem here ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837047/autolayout-complains-about-constraints-for-2-uitextfields-with-no-borders/30837324#30837324

Comment: as said in question they are all in XIB designer not in code , still there a way to post ?

Comment: When using AutoLayout you should always be careful which constraints you add. From my experience you should try to add each constraint manually and think of what you add where. This way you'll learn to understand AutoLayout and know what you need to tweak where to achieve your goal!

Comment: @OutOfBounds I agree but in this case when I test app on ulster it's working fine but doesn't on actual device that's my issue

Comment: I know. Does the debugger tell you that any constraints are broken?

Comment: at least post screenshots of constraints that have been applied

Comment: @OutOfBounds yes the designer shows red mark and asking me to add missing constraints but doesn't tell me what are those , can that be a cause ? But as said currently it works fine in emulator

Comment: @vishal Yes, that could be the root of the problem. That's why I initially said that adding constraints manually would be the preferred way to go ;-)

Comment: @OutOfBounds check additional image shows missing constraints

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't look like that big of a deal. Could you post a screenshot with all the constraints of the view?

Comment: Ok will do that in some time , do check back in some time please

Comment: @OutOfBounds added all the constraints

Comment: @EICaptain thanks I think that helped me trying as per what you show

Comment: @vishal glad it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a principle that you need to know..  Every view you add to the storyboard must have enough constraints to confirm it's:

1. Width
2. Height
3. X position
4. Y position

You should review the constrains you added.
Especially  the first textfield(Your Full Name).
Seems like it's Y position constrains wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You will get into problem 9 out of 10 times when Xcode adds missing constraints for you. I would suggest you to go for a better tutorial of autolayout.