# Xcode 7: UITextview doesn't aligned properly for 3 different sizes iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, swift, ios9, xcode7

I am trying to use adaptive layout in Xcode 7.1 for iPhone app. I am using 3 sizes iPhone device 5.5, 4.7 and 4.0 inches. When I added a background UIImageview, it fits nicely on all 3 iPhone screens. Please refer attached screenshot. I did pin option to Add 4 sides constraints with 0 values. Background fits to all 3 iPhone sizes screen fine.

Now, I am trying to add a UITextview in all 3 iPhone sizes screen. Now, this text view doesn't fit properly in all 3 iPhone sizes screen

Please find the screenshot reference below. How to make this textview properly placed on all 3 iPhone screens just below Employee ID label?

[image]

Comment: what is your constraints in textview or may be this  can help you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837047/autolayout-complains-about-constraints-for-2-uitextfields-with-no-borders/30837324#30837324

Comment: Ok sure, I'll check that link, thanks

Comment: select your textfiled->go to size inspector..and there you can see constraints of textfield if you give any...or check document outline

Comment: In that link you provided, there is a gif like video playing fast. Is it possible to slowly play that?

Comment: I tried like how it is being shown in that link. Choose Textview 1.) Set Horizontally in Container 2.) Click on Pin - Remove "Contrains to Margin", Choose "Width", Click on Top and Bottom Constraints and Add it. What it does is, increasing the height of the textview enormously.

Comment: delete bottom constraint and give height

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94202/discussion-between-ei-captain-and-stella).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this image and set your constraints like wise....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set constraints to fit textfield properly. Firstly you have to set size class before setting constraints to handle orientation. like [size class with respect to device size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html) in this screen shot size class RH/CW set for portrait orientation. And set set constraints to fit UITextfield [image]